Key recovery attack on BIP32-Ed25519
BIP32 describes a method for deriving secp256k1 key-pairs. BIP32-Ed25519 is a similar method for Ed25519. For both, the derivations proceed from a root key-pair by adding a random-like integer to the private key scalar. (The integer comes from HMAC-SHA512 applied to some available data.)
However, Ed25519 implementations have a high bit set, which led BIP32-Ed25519 to use only 224-bits from the HMAC result to add to the private key. The addition of many 224-bit integers avoids tripping over the high bit (bit 254) as long as the derivation paths aren't too long.
Jeff Burdges proposed a key recovery attack on BIP32-Ed25519. The idea is to make a derivation chain so long that the high bit changes. In the scheme, the attacker sends tiny amounts of unnamed currency and gets the victim to spend all the currency. When the high bit switches, a signature will fail and the attacker will know the transaction failed. The attacker observes where in the chain the failure occurs. Enough derivations occur that bits 224 to 254 are all on for the derived private key, and the addition of a 224-bit integer (with bit 224 set) flips bit 254 off.
"At this point, our attacker can make payments with derived keys that exhibit different bit patterns in the high bits of the scalars added to the secret keys, observe if the payments are cashed out, and adaptively select the next bits on which they focus"
My question is this: Once bit 224 is known, how are the remaining lower bits adaptively determined?
My thought was to use new derivations from the key right before the bit 254 overflow. Since the attacker doesn't control the hashes, this would require many (~2^224) derivations.

Your thought is correct and this doesn't affect the 224 lower bits. This is a mistake in the design that relies on $2^{30}$ derivation chain will not be reached.
